# Can I create my own question template under a permissive license to allow people to copy/paste it at will?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I submitted a question about a [move recommendation](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/37483/why-does-lichess-org-consider-this-castle-a-blunder). As my first question, I forked a well written [question](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/36866/why-does-chess-com-consider-this-promotion-a-blunder) by @[Fabio](https://chess.stackexchange.com/users/25130/fabio-says-reinstate-monica) who seems to fit perfectly. I forked it not by laziness, nor by "hoping to get the same rep". The question is well made, fitting, why reinvent the wheel? Like I wont roll my own crypto, I will use the right, relevant, tool for the job. I extracted a template and I submitted it with my own problem. Now, here is the thing, I forgot to post the original source and so my post was flagged as plagiarism (which I can't deny based on [What exactly is plagiarism?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160077/users-are-calling-me-a-plagiarist-what-do-i-do)). I meant no harm, but still, it does count. Per SE definition, plagiarizing the format (even without the content), is plagiarizing the question.

After reading comments on my question, I learnt that author credit may not be enough. @[Glorfindel](https://chess.stackexchange.com/users/7297/glorfindel) talked about "using my own word" and here is my question for meta: Would it be possible to create one template to ask this kind of question? I would like to avoid this kind of issue. I would even like to create an open source extension to link lichess move to SE. The goal would to avoid to rewrite something existing each time to focus of the problem not the frame. And having an open frame will help everyone. I am not the only non-native English speaker on SE, I think it could be useful.

Comment: Thanks for providing some insight *why* you copied that question. I hadn't thought of not being a non-native English speaker (even though that holds for me as well!) - using your own words is *better* but of course optional. (And it would be good to mention that too, even if it's just a footnote.)

Comment: Wait. if it is optional, could we copy/paste anything with sourcing only without entering in the plagiarism section? I thought not.

Comment: It's only plagiarism *if you try, explicitly or implicitly, to pass it off as your own work.* (from the FAQ you linked to). See also the [Help Center](https://chess.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) for what exactly is needed.

Comment: So after all the original close post would have been fine if I had not forgot to disclose the source of the frame of the question.

Comment: Yes. It might still not be well-received, but it wouldn't be deleted for plagiarism.

Comment: I will make my own template based on Rewan's answer. It is going to be under something akin to the wtfpl or the domain public.

Answer (score 1):

As the initial close voter, I agree that an open source template would is an excellent idea. Here is a quick sketch.

---

In this position, why/what is x move/sequence/etc. (details)?

*diagram*

I ask this because (details).

---

Of course, much more work is needed to tune a template to be broad enough for many questions while also being easy to use and understand.

Comment: Let's start here :)